# Copy a file from multiple folders

Tags: windows, xcopy

I'd like to use `xcopy` on a Windows machine to pull out all files with `.doc` extension into a single directory.

An example:

I need to copy the `.doc` file from the below source:

```
D:\new folder\new1\new1-1\new\y.doc  
D:\new folder\new2\new2-1\new\y.doc  
D:\new folder\new3\new3-1\new\y.doc  
D:\new folder\new4\new4-1\new\y.doc  
D:\new folder\new5\new5-1\new\y.doc  
:  
:  
:
```

And paste them in `D:\test\` as below:

```
y1.doc  
y2.doc  
y3.doc  
y4.doc  
y5.doc  
:  
:  
:
```

and avoid replacement of the `.doc` files.

Answer (score 1):

[FOR /R](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)

```
FOR /R %%G IN (.) DO COPY %%G %NEWFOLDER%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off & setlocal

for /s "D:\new folder" %%f in (*.doc) do call :nextfile "%%~f"
goto :eof

:nextfile
    set /a num+=1
    set "target=D:\test\%~n1%num%%~x1"
    if exist "%target%" goto :nextfile
    copy "%~1" "%target%"
    goto :eof
```

Comment: Don't say "I'd like to use *<some tool>*" unless you have a specific reason to use that tool and you know the tool can do what you're asking for. In this case, you can replace `copy` with `xcopy`, but you still have to use the script, and if you have many files it may even be slower (`xcopy` is an external process, while `copy` is built-in).

Answer (score 0):

```
for /L %a in (1,1,50) do XCOPY "D:\new folder\new%a\new%a-1\y.doc" D:\test\y%a.doc
```

replace "50" with whatever your ending folder number is.